# Switch values in Array from 0 to 1 and back

Tags: swift, int

I have the following array:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```

On some condition, I have to switch 0 to 1 and vice versa.

In JS I would do: `array[index] = !array[index]`, however, in Swift, this does not work.

Is there are an elegant way to do such conversions without using `if -> else` statements?

Comment: `array[index] = 1 - array[index]`

Comment: Why not use an array of `Bool` instead an array of `Int`?

Comment: One important point of Swift is that (contrary to many other languages) *"Values are never implicitly converted to another type,"* so an integer cannot be treated as a boolean or vice versa. – I'll suggest to read at least [A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html) from the Swift Programming Language book.

Answer (score 4):

Just use map:

```
array = array.map{1-$0}
```

Comment: Note that OP it is not asking how to toggle all values.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, Int cannot be converted to a Bool, and Bool cannot be converted to Int. That means you cannot do such a logical operation on an Int. I would suggest that you write your own operator, like this:

```
prefix operator !
prefix func !(value: Int) -> Int {
    return (value &+ 1) % 2
}
```

You can then write: `let i = !0 // i = 1` and `let i = !1 // i = 0`

You could use `Bool` instead of `Int`, as natively supported: `let b = !true // b = false` and `let b = !false // b = true`